# C# Windows Form Text is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new in programming with windows forms.
I created a server and a client, where the server is sending data to the client/clients in a byte array and the client is decoding it and updating his textboxes with the information it received.

My problem: it doesn't updates the actual form.

by clicking the button on the Form (ClientForm) a methode from another class is called which connects it to the server, and receives the data.
this data is then decoded (see below) and send to the Form Class through a String array where i want to update the textboxes.

here is some code that visualizes it:

EDIT:
I changed the example code so there wont be a unknown class

clientform:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
    {
        public ClientForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Experiment ex = new Experiment();
            ex.Hello();
        }

        // this methode is called outside of this class, see below
        public void SendDecodedData(List<String> data)
        {
          textbox1.Text = data[0];
          textbox2.Text = data[1];
          textbox3.Text = data[2];
        }
    }
```

By stopping the code at some of those changes, I can see that the textbox.Text is actually updated, however, it is not showing on the form.

other class

```
internal class Experiment
    {
        ClientForm client = new ClientForm();
        public void Hello()
        {
            List<String> list = new List<String>()
                    { "text1", "text2", "text3"};
            client.SendDecodedData(list);
        }

    }
```

If I call the methode SendDecodedData inside the form, for example instead of connecting:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> list = new List<String>()
                    { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"};
            SendDecodedData(list);
            
        }
```

it does work. There is some kind of rule that i dont know and cant find on the internet, that says how to change textboxes outside of the formclass.

Can anybody help me?

If the question isn't clearly stated or I forgot important informations, please comment and let me know! I dont ask a lot on here.

The problem is similar to the one linked below, but no answers helped unfortunately.

[C# TextBox Control Not Updating With New Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969195/c-sharp-textbox-control-not-updating-with-new-text)

Comment: The linked question actually has a *lot* of relevant answers. Updating a visible TextBox's Text property works. If it didn't millions of developers would have noticed 20 years ago. The code you posted never *displays* the form it creates, which means whatever you're seeing is a different form.

Comment: You don't show how you call `DecodeReceivedData` so it's a little difficult to give you a clear answer.

Comment: totally understandable, i will give you a more simple example

Comment: I now see that "ClientForm client = new ClientForm();" is the problem, but how do i change that?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new form instance inside `DecodeReceivedData` to set the text boxes on, but this won't be the same form instance that is being shown to the user which is why those changes you make are not visible.

Rather than creating a new `ClientForm` inside `DecodeReceivedData`, you can simply pass that `List<string>` back and have the form itself update the text boxes.

Your `Experiment` class would then look like this (note the change in the `Hello` method to return back a `List<string>`):

```
internal class Experiment
{
    public List<string> Hello()
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>()
                { "text1", "text2", "text3"};
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now when you create your `Expermiment` instance and call the `Hello` method, you'd store that returned list and use the items in it to update your form's text boxes:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Experiment ex = new Experiment();
    List<string> data = ex.Hello();
    
    textbox1.Text = data[0];
    textbox2.Text = data[1];
    textbox3.Text = data[2];
}
```

The original question mentioned connecting to a server to request the information you need to show. Assuming that is using something like `HttpClient` to issue those requests, you can use `async` and `await` to keep the code pretty much the same:

```
internal class Experiment
{
    public Task<List<string>> Hello()
    {
        //You'd want to create a single instance of HttpClient and re-use it in a real application
        using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://your-server");

            //Do something with response to get your list 
            
            return result;
        }
    }
}

//Be aware there are some gotcha's with async void around handling
//errors. Using it on event handlers is the only time you'd ever need
//to do this
private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Experiment ex = new Experiment();
    List<string> data = await ex.Hello();

    textbox1.Text = data[0];
    textbox2.Text = data[1];
    textbox3.Text = data[2];
}
```

And your

Comment: A far cleaner option would be to return the `List<string>` and let the form update itself. `DecodeReceivedData` doesn't need to know about forms

Comment: Good point. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: "you can simply pass that `List<string>` back and have the form itself update the text boxes" is terribly unclear. How do you simply do thaqt?

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I don't fully understand

Comment: It seemed clear enough to me but have expanded my answer to hopefully make things more obvious.

Comment: This is totally solving the example problem. Thank you! however in my actual code the List of strings is not immediately ready to be used. That was my bad tho, to not clearly sate my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd added a quick example of using `async` and `await` to demonstrate fetching data from a remote server to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of the form and not using the one that already exists. It's like you have two bank accounts and you're depositing in one and wondering why the balance of the other hasn't changed.

There are two simple ways to solve this.

The first is pass the reference to the current form:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Experiment ex = new Experiment();
        ex.Hello(this);
    }

    public void SendDecodedData(List<String> data)
    {
        textbox1.Text = data[0];
        textbox2.Text = data[1];
        textbox3.Text = data[2];
    }
}

internal class Experiment
{
    public void Hello(ClientForm client)
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>()
                    { "text1", "text2", "text3"};
        client.SendDecodedData(list);
    }
}
```

But that's not ideal because it makes a dependency inside the `class Experiment`.

It's better to not pass the form around, instead the data:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Experiment ex = new Experiment();
        this.SendDecodedData(ex.Hello());
    }

    private void SendDecodedData(List<String> data)
    {
        textbox1.Text = data[0];
        textbox2.Text = data[1];
        textbox3.Text = data[2];
    }
}

internal class Experiment
{
    public List<String> Hello()
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>() { "text1", "text2", "text3"};
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

Option 3 - use an event:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Experiment ex = new Experiment();
        ex.HelloData += (s, data) => this.SendDecodedData(data);
        ex.Hello();
    }

    private void SendDecodedData(List<String> data)
    {
        textbox1.Text = data[0];
        textbox2.Text = data[1];
        textbox3.Text = data[2];
    }
}

internal class Experiment
{
    public event EventHandler<List<String>> HelloData;
    public void Hello()
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>() { "text1", "text2", "text3"};
        this.HelloData?.Invoke(this, list);
    }
}
```

This final approach avoids the need for the `class Experiment` to know anything about the form - which is good. And it allows the form not the be the one that calls `Hello`.

---

Option 4 - `async`/`await`:

```
public partial class ClientForm : Form
{
    public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Experiment ex = new Experiment();
        this.SendDecodedData(await ex.HelloAsync());
    }

    private void SendDecodedData(List<String> data)
    {
        textbox1.Text = data[0];
        textbox2.Text = data[1];
        textbox3.Text = data[2];
    }
}

internal class Experiment
{
    public Task<List<String>> HelloAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            List<String> result = new List<String>() { "text1", "text2", "text3" };
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

In the comments discussion you say that the call to `Hello` prevents the button click event from completing then you need use `async`/`await` to prevent your UI locking up.

Comment: Thank you!! Unfortunately in the actual code i wont be calling the methode (which needs the ClientForm form (this)) in the actual clientform. So the client needs to wait till it receives data and then updates it's textboxes. But i didnt make it clear in my question. thank you so much tho!!

Comment: @clara - The second option I put forward does this just fine.

Comment: @clara - You need to clarify what you meant by the " the actual code i wont be calling the methode (which needs the ClientForm form (this)) in the actual clientform".

Comment: the connect button calls a methode ConnectToServer() that connects to the server, then it reads the callback and calls a methode to decode the byte array that was received. this methode that decodes the array sends it then to the form and SendDecodedData should update the textboxes. That is my plan:)

Comment: @clara - That is a bad plan. Always separate UI from data. So the `ConnectToServer()` method should know nothing about the form. Just have it return the data - as with my option #2.

Comment: i understand, however, is it somehow possible that not the form is calling the method? I want that the method is calling the method in the form or is "sending" it when it has it

Comment: @elisabeth - Then you need an `event`. I've added option #3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247477/discussion-between-elisabeth-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the `ClientForm` constructor to be able to receive data?

```
        public ClientForm(List<String> list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (list != null)
            {
                 //do stuff...
                 //save to private var like "List<String> pvtList"
            }
            else
            {
                 //use Enigmativity sugestion
            }
        }
```